# How to make installable extension for OpenCart4

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I have an custom extension that is working fine with OpenCart V2 and V3 but when I try to install that extension on V4 it is showing that there is no install.json file in it.

I created a new custom extension having only install.json in it as mentioned in one tutorial but the error remain same.
Can anyone help with it 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

so create this install.json
file instead install.xml
file must contain:

```
{
  "name": "extension name",
  "version": "x.x.x.x",
  "author": "author name",
  "link": "https://your_site.com"
}
```

But this not only install.json file issue. you should to check how  modules is build in Version OC4. File structure is changed.

Comment: I am trying to find a tutorial but no luck yet